# Multiple definition when using namespace in header file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define a global namespace in a header file `global.h`.

```
...
namespace g {
   const int g_0 = 0;
   const int g_1 = 1;
}
...
```

When JUST `#include "global.h"` in other .cpp file, compiler gives an error

```
multiple definition of g::g_0
multiple definition of g::g_1
```

If I try to use `g_0` and `g_1` in other .cpp files, for example.

```
int g_0_copy = g::g_0;
int g_1_copy = g::g_1;
```

It throws an error saying:

```
ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member...
```

Is there something special when using namespace to declare global variable?
(I have to use c++98 in this case)

Comment: The compiler issues an error if the namespace is included twice in the same compilation unit. Otherwise the constants have static linkage.

Comment: Silly question. Do you have include guards in the header?

Comment: Need full code. The note about `in-class initialization` tells me there is more than you show us.

Comment: @StoryTeller xD. Silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of your globals are `const`, you most likely merely need include guards.

```
#ifndef   GLOBAL_H
#define   GLOBAL_H

...
namespace g {
   const int g_0 = 0;
   const int g_1 = 1;
}
...

#endif // GLOBAL_H
```

[`const` global variables have internal linkage unless explicitly declared `extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), so they won't cause linking errors as long as they're only defined once per translation unit.  Each translation unit will have its own copy of each global constant, which the compiler may or may not optimise out if possible.

---

If some of your globals aren't `const`, however, it gets a bit more complex.

```
#ifndef   GLOBAL_H
#define   GLOBAL_H

...
namespace g {
   const int g_0 = 0;
   const int g_1 = 1;

   int g_2 = 2; // Oh, boy.
}
...

#endif // GLOBAL_H
```

As this variable has external linkage by default, it will cause a linking error due to multiple translation units containing different variables named `g_2`.  The solution here is to declare the variables `extern` in the header, and place their actual definitions in a source file.

```
// global.h
#ifndef   GLOBAL_H
#define   GLOBAL_H

...
namespace g {
   const int g_0 = 0;
   const int g_1 = 1;

   extern int g_2; // Oh, boy.
}
...

#endif // GLOBAL_H

// ---

// global.cpp
namespace g {
   int g_2 = 2;
}
```

---

That said, as [SergeyA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245033/sergeya) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514928/multiple-definition-when-using-namespace-in-header-file#comment68271902_40514928), the error message you got indicates that there's more to this:

```
ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member...
```

I can't say anything about this, without knowing what code is causing it.